# Use Slick Slider as WP Post Navigation

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slick.js

I'm trying to use slick slider as the Previous and Next buttons on a WordPress single CPT page.

So the slider would call all the posts of a specific CPT and show the featured image of the current post and on either side it would show the featured image of the previous and next posts.

As you navigate through the slide the corresponding content would appear.

The problem is that as you slide through you'll get the correct images and content, but the URL stays the same. Also you can't link to a specific post because it'll just go to the beginning of the slide.

Right now, this is what my `single-CPT.php` looks like

```
<?php
get_header();
rewind_posts();
if (have_posts()) {
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$post_id = get_the_ID();

?>
 // BEGIN SLIDER (WHERE FEATURED IMAGES ARE THE SLIDES)//
<section class="slider center">

<?php

    $index = 0;
    $carousel_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'CPT',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,


    );
    $carousel_query = new WP_Query( $carousel_args );
    if ( $carousel_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $carousel_query->have_posts() ) {
            $carousel_query->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $link = get_permalink();

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $post_thumbnail_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'large' );
                $post_thumb = $post_thumbnail_image[0];
            } else {
                $post_thumb = '';
            }
            $content = get_the_content();
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

            // output//
            ?>

                <div class="wow slide-in slide">
                    <div class="active">

                       <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                       <img src="<?php echo $post_thumb; ?>" />
                       </a>                 
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php   $index++;
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile;
?>
</section>
//END SLIDER - BEGIN CONTENT//      
<div id="archive-post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-10 medium-offset-1 large-offset-0 large-8">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
                    <div class="post-title">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="columns">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="columns">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Basically I need the URL to update along with the slide without refreshing the page. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so with a ton of help from a friend, I found a way to do this with the magic of AJAX and HTML5 Apis

Basically what you have to do is use the HTML5 Api to manipulate the browser's history, and use AJAX to load the desired content without refreshing. Here's what it ended up looking like:

The single post template stayed pretty much the same except I changed the slide query output a little from

`<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">`

to

`<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="js-switchSlide" data-ajaxurl="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">`

I added the `js-switchSlide` class to be able to call it in my JS and AJAX functions later.
I added a couple of data attributes (`data-ajaxurl`,`data-title`, and `data-id`) that I will use in the ajax function.

The content section has been changed too, notice the new classes and id's

`<div id="archive-post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-10 medium-offset-1 large-offset-0 large-8">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array('post-page', 'js-slideContainer') ); ?> role="article">
          <input type="hidden" id="currentSlide" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="post-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <h3 class="js-slideTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns js-slideContent">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Here is the JS:

`$(document).ready(function() {`

This is used later to see whether the actual slide or the button was clicked

```
`var clickedSlide = true;`
```

Initiate the slide

`$navslider = $('.slider').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,`

Here I make the slide responsive

```
        `responsive: [
          {
        breakpoint: 1068,
            settings: {
            initialSlide: 0,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
          }
        },
          {
        breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
            initialSlide: 0,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
          }
        },
            {
        breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
            initialSlide: 0,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },]
});`
```

Here is my Ajax call

```
`function slidesAjaxCall(slideID, slideTitle, slideHref, ajaxurl) {`
```

This part just makes the loading of the content a little smoother by fading it in and out.

```
    `$( '.js-slideContainer' ).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 320);`
```

This is where I manipulate the browser history

```
    `history.pushState(null, slideTitle, slideHref);
    document.title = slideTitle;`
```

Here is where I place the values from the data attributes using POST method. Type is just the custom post type and action is the name of the Ajax function.

`$.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: slideID,
                type : 'CPT',
                action: 'hc_load_slide'
            },`

Self explanatory

```
        `error : function( response ){
            console.log('error');
        },`
```

If successful:
            `success : function( response ){
                if( response === 0 ){
                    console.log('no slide found');

```
                $( '.js-slideContainer' ).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 320);

            } else {`
```

The post data is collected in the Ajax function in JSON format so it has to be parsed and inserted into the html
                    `var data = JSON.parse(response);

```
                $( '.js-slideTitle' ).text(data.title);
                $( '.js-slideContent' ).html(data.content);`
```

Make it behave nicely
                    `setTimeout(function(){

```
                    $( '.js-slideContainer' ).animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 320);

                }, 100);
            }
        }
    });

}`
```

`.js-switchSlide` is the class in the `a` tag so I prevent it from going refreshing the page when clicked.

```
`$('.js-switcSlide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();`
```

This says that the slide was clicked, this will keep it from calling the ajax function twice

```
    `clickedSlide = true;`
```

Collect all the values from the data attributes:

```
    `var babyID = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var babyTitle = e.currentTarget.dataset.title;
    var babyHref = e.currentTarget.href;
    var ajaxurl = e.currentTarget.dataset.ajaxurl;`
```

Call the function

```
    `babiesAjaxCall(babyID, babyTitle, babyHref, ajaxurl);

});`
```

Okay this next part loads the appropriate slide and content using the permalink. Remember, one of the issues was that I could get the slide to work fine, but when I navigated to a specific post the slide would start from the beginning.

```
`var currentSlideID = $( '#currentSlide' ).val();
var $slide = $(".slider [data-id='" + currentSlide + "']");
var slideIndex = $slide.parents('.slide').data("slick-index");
$babyslider.slick("goTo", slideIndex);

/* Trigger Ajax call if Chevron is clicked and not Slide */
$slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    // Stop if clieckedSlide === true;
    if (clickedSlide) {
        clickedSlide = false;
        return;
    }

    var slideIndex = $('[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]').find('.js-switchSlide');

    var slideID = slideIndex.data('id');
    var slideTitle = slideIndex.data('title');
    var slideHref = slideIndex.attr('href');
    var ajaxurl = slideIndex.data('ajaxurl');

    babiesAjaxCall(babyID, babyTitle, babyHref, ajaxurl);

});

});`
```

Meanwhile, the Ajax function looks like this

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_hc_load_slide', 'hc_load_slide' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_hc_load_slide', 'hc_load_slide' );

function hc_load_baby() {

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$type = $_POST["type"];

// echo $id . ' - ' . $type;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'p' => $id,
);

$slide = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $slide->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $slide ->have_posts() ) : $slide->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content() );

    endwhile;

endif;

echo json_encode([ 'title' => $title, 'content' => $content ]);

die();
}`
```

I know it's a long answer, but I hope that makes sense. It accomplishes exactly what I wanted. Thanks alecaddd for the lessons.